# Magento 2: How to do telephone number masking?

Tags: magento2

I want to set telephone masking(US Country telephone number format) in my customer registration form how can i do that?
In US telephone number format is (999) 999-9999 now i want to in my customer registration form when i click on telephone number field then above phone number format maskin should open.[image: please refer the screenshot]

Comment: Please add more details

Comment: @Jai please check my updated answer

Comment: @prashant valanda if you know please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below code you need to implement it in Magento 2.

```
$('#phoneNumber').inputmask("(999) 999-9999");
```

And then this.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

<label class="control-label col-sm-2">Phone Number:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">          
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber" value="">
</div>
```

Here is the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43130272/jquery-input-mask-for-phone-number) from where I got it and here code snippets also to check.

Hope it will help you and Happy Coding.